# WordPress path url in js script file

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I added custom script:

```
wp_enqueue_script('functions', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/functions.js', 'search', null, false);
```

It works great, except in the `functions.js` I have:

```
Reset.style.background = "url('../images/searchfield_clear.png') no-repeat top left";
```

This used to work before, until I changed to pretty permalinks and .htaccess

The folder hierarchy is like:

> `themename/js themename/images` (the images and js folder are in themename folder)

I tried ../images - ./image - /images

Normally it should go back 1 level wherever the js file is located....

I don't want to use full path.

Is there another way that WordPress can recognize in the javascript file to have the correct path?

Currently I am just confused what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could avoid hardcoding the full path by setting a JS variable in the header of your template, before `wp_head()` is called, holding the template URL. Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>
```

And use that variable to set the background (I realize you know how to do this, I only include these details in case they helps others):

```
Reset.style.background = " url('"+templateUrl+"/images/searchfield_clear.png') ";
```

Comment: This solution works fine, but Chris answer is preferable in most situations - I didn't know about the existence of wp_localize_script().

Comment: I found [this article](http://waterstreetgm.org/passing-php-variables-to-javascript-with-wp_localize_script/) useful. Helped me implement `wp_localize_script()`

Comment: Is there any reason why this would not work in 2014? besides the `<?php` and the weird quote style?

Comment: `<?php bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>` and 

`'url(' + templateUrl + '/images/path-to-image.png)'` would tune this baby up.

Answer (score 120):

According to the Wordpress documentation, you should use [`wp_localize_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) in your functions.php file. This will create a Javascript Object in the header, which will be available to your scripts at runtime.

See [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Example:

```
<?php wp_localize_script('mylib', 'WPURLS', array( 'siteurl' => get_option('siteurl') )); ?>
```

To access this variable within in Javascript, you would simply do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = WPURLS.siteurl;
</script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you also showed how to fetch the variable in JavaScript. I know it shows how in the link, but it would make a more complete answer.

Comment: Maybe this note from the documentation should be mentioned as well: **IMPORTANT!** ``wp_localize_script()`` MUST be called *after* the script has been registered using ``wp_register_script()`` or ``wp_enqueue_script()``.

Comment: > `wp_add_inline_script()` was introduced in WP v4.5, and is now the best
> practice for that use case. `wp_localize_script()` should only be used
> when you actually want to localize strings.

Answer (score 28):

```
    wp_register_script('custom-js',WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/PLUGIN_NAME/js/custom.js',array(),NULL,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js');

    $wnm_custom = array( 'template_url' => get_bloginfo('template_url') );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'wnm_custom', $wnm_custom );
```

and in custom.js

```
alert(wnm_custom.template_url);
```

Comment: this is definitely the best and easiest way! Thank you!

Comment: I know this is an old post, but to get the child themes URL use  'get_stylesheet_directory_uri()' instead of 'get_bloginfo('template_url')'.

Answer (score 7):

If the javascript file is loaded from the admin dashboard, this javascript function will give you the root of your WordPress installation. I use this a lot when I'm building plugins that need to make ajax requests from the admin dashboard.

```
function getHomeUrl() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  var index = href.indexOf('/wp-admin');
  var homeUrl = href.substring(0, index);
  return homeUrl;
}
```

Comment: Can I able to get localized variable in the theme's functions.php that set from the plugin file?

Answer (score 1):

For users working with the Genesis framework.

Add the following to your child theme `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'genesis_before', 'script_urls' );

function script_urls() {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var stylesheetDir = '<?= get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory"); ?>';
    </script>
<?php
}
```

And use that variable to set the relative url in your script. For example:

```
Reset.style.background = " url('"+stylesheetDir+"/images/searchfield_clear.png') ";
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work by using this method...

1: Adding the callback function into the header

```
function custom_header() {
// Define siteURL for JS
echo '<script>var url = "'.home_url().'";</script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_header' );
```

2: Call the URL inside any desired JS file as follows:

```
$.infinitescroll.defaults = {
      loading: {
        msgText: 'Loading...',
        img: "" + url + "/path_to_folder/loader.gif",
      }
```

**Hope it can help anyone looking to include a site URL in inner JS or CSS files.**