# How to put var url in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have made a declaration like this in php (taken from [WordPress path url in js script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var templateurl = "<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>";
</script>
```

then i have this code in my javascript (myjava.js):

```
init : function(ed, url) {

        ed.addCommand('mcearrow_shortcodes', function() {
            ed.windowManager.open({
                file : url + '/interface.php',
                width : 410 + ed.getLang('arrow_shortcodes.delta_width', 0),
                height : 250 + ed.getLang('arrow_shortcodes.delta_height', 0),
                inline : 1
            }, {
                plugin_url : url
            });
        });


        ed.addButton('arrow_shortcodes', {
            title : 'arrow_shortcodes.desc',
            cmd : 'mcearrow_shortcodes',
            image : url + '/btn.png'
        });


        ed.onNodeChange.add(function(ed, cm, n) {
            cm.setActive('arrow_shortcodes', n.nodeName == 'IMG');
        });
    },
```

I want to change all the 'url +' with templateurl, I've tried to use this:

```
 file : templateurl + '/includes/scripts/interface.php'
```

But it doesn't work. It doesn't load the interface.php. However, if I use 'url +', the interface.php is loaded perfectly.
Problem is, I want to put my interface.php in different folder. Not in the same folder where myjava.js is located.

What's the correct way to use my templateurl variable?

Many thanks!

Comment: does the `templateurl` have a value? what is the outcome?

Comment: How is the init method being called? Who passes it the `url` param?

Comment: You haven't posted all your code. It looks like you're defining members of some object, but you haven't shown what object. And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens instead? Have you tried inspecting the value in a debugger?

Comment: I've edited my question to make it clear :)

Comment: seeing that `templateurl` is global, it should be seen in your script. **are you sure** `templateurl` has the right value? if it doesn't work, what happens? 404? 500? at this state, nothing's ever going to be answered until details are given.

Comment: put the definition over the script loading tag.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
 var templateurl = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') ?>";

 document.write(templateurl )



 </script>

Still not loaded. I checked templateurl  has the correct value.

Answer (score 2):

Do the templateurl has the value? Please check it. You are assigning php variable so please echo it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var templateurl = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
 var templateurl = "<?php echo bloginfo('template_url') ?>";

 document.write(templateurl )



 </script>

Still not loaded. I checked templateurl  has the correct value.

Comment: I think value of the templateurl is not available inside myjava.js. Have you loaded myjava.js after the templateurl got assigned with the value

Comment: I put the declaration of templateurl above wp_head() in my the head section

Comment: Please put the <script type="text/javascript" src="myjava.js"></script> line below all of the php code

Comment: it looks like the templateurl got the issue.
If I put this = #file : url + 'http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/includes/scripts/interface.php'#, it brings up a pop up with 404 error inside the pop up windows.
If I put this = #file : 'http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/includes/scripts/interface.php'#, it brings up a pop up the correct interface.php inside the windows (which I want)

Comment: If I put this = #file : templateurl + 'http://mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/includes/scripts/interface.php'#, it doesn't even bring a pop up at all.

Comment: Did you got the templateurl value inside myjava.js? If so, does the templateurl starts with http:// and then your path

Comment: How to check the templateurl value inside myjava.js? :s
I used document.write(templateurl ) inside the function, but it didnt work.

Comment: alert(templateurl); will alert the value

Comment: still not working.
For now, I just put it in the same folder, although it's not the way I want, but it works.
Still need for an answer though.