# Changing image src with javascript with an variable in it

Tags: javascript, image, wordpress

I made an template in HTML and now i am putting it in as an wordpress template. But in my .js file i got this:

```
    $('.tab_home').find('img').attr('src', '/images/home.png');
```

This is part of an click function and changes the image when i click on something. And it works fine in HTML but when i want to put this is in wordpress it is broken because the src url is wrong ofcourse. Now i did find this thread: [WordPress path url in js script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file) and this would be part of my solution except that i can't put `"+templateUrl+"`in my `.attr('src', '/images/home.png')`Cause then i get an link like:

```
<img alt="" src=""+templateUrl+"/images/home.png">
```

Does some1 know what im doing wrong here, and how to fix it?

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do it as follows:

```
$('.tab_home').find('img').attr('src', templateUrl + '/images/home.png');
```

And don't forget to set templateUrl in the header of the template, as described in post you're referring to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Ow my ... Your totaly right, thanks alot. (I had the templateUrl right btw, just the syntax in my js file wrong.)