# Wordpress root URL with Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, root

I am using this script on my Wordpress website: [JQuery Plugin: Random Image](http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/)

The problem I have is that I don't know what sort of code to put in the path section so that Wordpress would be able to fetch the images from the images folder. /images is not enough, since it'll just give me www.mydomain.com/images/image.jpg, and obviously that is not the whole URL when using Wordpress.

I tried this: [wordpress path url in js script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file)

I can't get it to work however. Whenever I place

```
var templateUrl = '<?= get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';
```

in my file, I just get an error

```
%3C?=%20get_bloginfo(%22template_url%22);%20?%3E/images/image.jpg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to try `var templateUrl = '<?php get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>';`

Comment: Still gives me the same error :(

Comment: If you are getting all the percent encoding than it sounds like php isn't processing the file.  Is this all in a js file?

Comment: Using that php call inside a JS file will not work. You could hardcode the path. It's not ideal, but might be worth it if it's in a file you'll be updating frequently.

Comment: In the same stackoverflow question that you linked, another answer mentions the function wp_localize_script.  You might want to look into that.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot hardcode it because the picture it is supposed to display is in the header, so the hardcode path will be changing, e.g. ../themes/themename/contact/images/image.jpg and ../themes/themename/about/images/image.jpg etc. So the page you are currently on will always be changing the hardcode path. Therefore it is important for me to get some kind of code inside the JS.

Comment: And PhoenixWing156, unfortunately I am not really familiar with JS to be able to utilize that script as I don't know how :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it working through trial and error and I will list here things that I did wrong, just in case someone else is having the same problem:

1. I put the **var templateUrl** code in separate javascript tags. Later on I moved it just above **$(document).ready(function() {**
2. I put **templateUrl** in the actual .js file. I later on moved it to:
   **$('.shuffle').randomImage({path: templateUrl + /images/});**

The end result looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var templateUrl = '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.shuffle').randomImage({path: templateUrl + /images/});
    });
</script>
```

The script is now working perfectly! Thanks to everyone for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to echo it.

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_url"); ?>
```

or you can use

```
<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>
```

Comment: Neither of those work. I am still getting the percentages inbetween the PHP code :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var themeFolder = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'; 
</script>
```