# Is it possible to specify different behaviour for clicked links, depending on URL?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, href

I have a site that uses an iFrame to contain a Wordpress site (for my blog).  I'm using an iFrame because I want Wordpress to inherit my site wide header and footer.  The problem with this approach is that, when a link is clicked in Wordpress, new pages open in the iFrame.  This might be correct behaviour (clicking to a new blog page for example), or incorrect behaviour (clicking to a different site).
I'd like to be able to decide how the link should be handled - have a list for links that open in the frame and a list for links that should replace all the content on the page.  Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on click check if the url domain/name matches yours, then open in iframe, else open on the same page

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines - but how does one perform that kind of checking in Wordpress?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121041/wordpress-root-url-with-javascript