# Replace src attribute with javascript – getting a relative path –

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a 1.5mb .png that I have to use on a site. No choice.

I only need in on a desktop though.

This project in a WordPress project, so It's PHP. My problem is that I can't seem to get a clean relative link path to use in the `js` and for the various scenarios I have going on between local and live.

### PHP

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/smaller-version-of-image" alt="yeah">
```

### jQuery

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

if ( windowWidth > 1200 ) {

    $('#flare01 img').attr('src','./images/larger-version-of-image.png');

}
```

There are a few factors. The local WP install is in the root. The live WP install lives in a subfolder but has it's setting set to the root. - so that is a WordPress specific part. The site points to mysite.com - but the WP is in mysite.com/phoebe

I don't really know why any of that should matter though – between the `HTML` and `js file`My logic is that my js file is in the js folder `js/scripts.js` in the root theme. The images are in the `images`folder – so, *pop out* of the js, and then into the images `./images/image.png` but that doesn't give me the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use ".." instead of "." if you want to go one level up in the hierarchy:

```
$('#flare01 img').attr('src','../images/larger-version-of-image.png');
```

"." refers to the current working directory.

You might try retrieving the URL of your WP site and store in a variable, to use when constructing your image URLs, something along the lines of this: [WordPress path url in js script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file)

Comment: That takes me to `mysite.com/images/images/larger-version-of-image.png` which would be great, but unfortunately the image really lives at `mysite.com/phoebe/wp-content/themes/theme-name/images/etc...`

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed the finer details of the WP aspect of your implementation. You might try retrieving the URL of your WP site and store in a variable, to use when constructing your image URLs. Something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file

Comment: Those are great leads. So far haven't got them to work. I have hope though.

Comment: Got it. I have a messy site with multiple headers and was putting it in the wrong place. Add that link to your answer and I'll mark it solved. Thanks.