# How to use java script variable in site_url() php?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".galleryvideo").click(function(){
   vidid = this.id;

   window.location = "<?php echo site_url().$this->uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/video/'; ?>"+vidid;
});
</script>
```

I want to use java script variable insitd site_url function.

eg.  window.location = "uri->segment(1).'/'.$this->uri->segment(2).'/video/'); ?>";

Because in codeignter framework i gave url_suffix i.e. : .htm.

html tag as suffix is used when parameter is passed inner site_url();

Please help...

Comment: Did you refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file ?

Comment: So you basically want to grab a Javascript variable, "give it" to PHP so it can use it inside site_url() function. Correct?