# Wordpress - How do I take the theme directory in a js file?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have an external script to integrate in a Wordpress theme. This script has different mixed resources in it like js, php files, etc.
It's something like:

```
/mytheme/myscript/
                  ...main.php
                  ...folder/main.js
```

Now, `main.js` post to `main.php` and uses something like:

```
var comet = new vpb_start_comet('main.php');
comet.connect();
```

My problem's here. `Main.php` is not found because I should change it with the relative wordpress path, being in a subfolder of my theme. So how could I `get_bloginfo('template_url').'/myfolder/main.php` in my `main.js` file?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress path url in js script file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file)

Comment: @SetSailMedia Great Man! Thanks to your suggestion I've found the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `folder/main.js` is being included via the `wp_enqueue_script()` function ( which it probably should be, as this is the proper method with WP to load scripts ), then you can easily add the theme directory uri as a variable using the `localize_script()' function like so:

```
wp_localize_script( 'script_handle', 'themeDirURI', get_template_directory_uri() ) ;
```

You would put this code after the wp_enqueue for the `main.js` script.  This will make the theme directory available as a javascript variable named `themeDirURI`, and the value will be something like:  `http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/'

Hope this helps!