# Wordpress: path to my img in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, path

I know it is good practice to register a javascript file in wordpress (functions.php). But how exactly is this done?

I used to do it this way in the head:

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Then in my script.js file i have 2 lines of code:

```
var openmenu = "assets/menu.svg";
var closemenu = "assets/close-menu.svg";
```

But when i move my wordpress site online, the svg's won't load. I know it has something to do with wp_enqueue_script but i can't seem to figure out how exactly...

Many thanks!

Comment: Afaik, paths like that are relative to the current location, not the location of the script. Where exactly is your assets folder located?

Comment: It is located in the location of the style.css file, aka the get_stylesheet_directory_uri()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress - How do I take the theme directory in a js file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726823/wordpress-how-do-i-take-the-theme-directory-in-a-js-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to register your scripts, like this (on your theme's functions.php)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_register_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/my-script.js', array('jquery'), '3.14', true );
});
```

Where:

- `'my-script'` is an id for your script (whatever you want)
- `get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/my-script.js'` it's the full URL to your script
- `array('jquery')` are the dependencies for the script -- if there are no dependencies, just use an empty `array()`. If you're adding a new script that depends on the previously registered `'my-script'` (or whatever "id" you used), you can use `array('jquery', 'my-script')`
- `'3.14'` it's a version number for your script
- `true` indicates that the script can be loaded on the footer (better for the page load speed)

Then, using the "id" for enqueued script:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_register_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/my-script.js', array('jquery'), '3.14', true );
    wp_localize_script('my-script', 'MyScript', array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'stuff' => get_option('quick_brown_fox'),
        'menu' => get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/menu.svg',
        'close_menu' => get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/close_menu.svg'
    ));
});
```

That way, whenever you load the "my-script" script, WordPress will create a "MyScript" javascript global that you can later use on your js file to get that value.

So, on your js, now you can use:

```
var closeMenuImgPath = MyScript.close_menu;
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thx!