# Get js file directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

in js file, I have below code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("ul.colors .color1").click(function () {
        $("#colors").attr("href", "wp-content/plugins/hekim/widgets/bclinico/css/colors/default.css");
        return false;
   })
});
```

it works only on the homepage because on other pages, it adds page name to the url.for example:

on the home page: `link.com/.../defauls.css` works

on contact page: `link.com/contact-page/default.css` not working

how can I write directly js file url instead of `wp-content/...` to href?

it works under wordpress, I can do it easily with `php/wordpress code but it is in a js file and I want to make it with js or jquery code.

Comment: I think if you precede it with a `/` and give the full path from the root, that'll do what you're asking.

Comment: I dont want use "wp-content/plugins/.." because it is a theme file.if website changes, it will be broken.I want to learn js file url and write it to href.

Comment: Try to check [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221630/wordpress-path-url-in-js-script-file)